# Samsung Nexus tablet wierd zoom on click

Tags: android, zooming, galaxy-nexus

Client said he is using Samsung Nexus tablet.

There is simple list and onClick event it opens subsections.
Like this:
[image: normal]

When you click on London or on any red submenu browser does some zoom.
[image: zoom]

So if anyone could explain what it is I would be grateful.
And if it can be somehow disabled using some meta value or JS.

Comment: This is a feature of the chrome browser that zooms in when it's not sure which link you meant to tap on. I doubt you can disable this client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disable this.

If you click a link that is very close to another link the browser will do this so you can tap the one you actually want.

Many (myself included) like it this way.

Comment: Probably then fix could be just make links more distant. Thanks for info.

Comment: @ViszinisA it depends, what if the viewer has zoomed out? Make it look nice, imagine this feature isn't there. It is a good thing! It is important with UIs that users expect and understand it. If you have a dialogue that appears and 99% of the time yes is the answer (think are you sure?) that one time it is not, you click yes by mistake! Users expect this, it takes the pressure off to aim at the screen. Also worth noting Android onClick events (the ones for actual programs) contain a pointer size. If I put my thumb on the screen I may get it regardless. Remember to upvote and tick :)

Comment: Mby mby. You are probably right. I usually forget that not everyone is coder and know how to use things.

Comment: empiric testing, how close is to close (in normal view) would be worthwhile.